# Delphi 7: Handling events in console application (TidIRC)

Tags: delphi, events, delphi-7, console-application, indy

I'm trying to make a console application based on Indy's IRC Component (TIdIRC) but I'm having trouble with events. Here's my code:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  Classes,
  Math,
  IdBaseComponent,
  IdComponent,
  IdTCPConnection,
  IdTCPClient,
  IdIRC;

type
  TEvents = class
  public
    procedure Raw(Sender: TObject; AUser: TIdIRCUser; ACommand, AContent: String; var Suppress: Boolean);
  end;

const
  IrcServ = 'gr.irc.gr';
  IrcPort = 6667;
  IrcChan = '#lalala';

var
  Irc: TidIRC;
  Event: TEvents;
  uName, rName: string;

function Log(s: string): string;
var now: TDateTime;
begin
  now := Time;
  result := FormatDateTime('[hh:nn:ss] ', now) + s;
end;

procedure TEvents.Raw(Sender: TObject; AUser: TIdIRCUser; ACommand, AContent: String; var Suppress: Boolean);
begin
  Log(AUser.Nick+' '+ACommand+' '+AContent);
end;

begin
  Event := TEvents.Create;
  Irc := TidIRC.Create(nil);
  Irc.OnRaw := Event.Raw;
  Randomize;
  Write('Nickname: ');
  ReadLn(uName);
  rName := 'IDM' + IntToStr(RandomRange(1000, 9999)) + uName;
  with Irc do begin
    AltNick := 'IDM' + IntToStr(RandomRange(1000, 9999)) + uName;
    Nick := rName;
    Username := rName;
    RealName := 'I.D.M.';
    Host := IrcHost;
    Port := IrcPort;
    //MaxLineAction := maException;  <-- [ERROR] Undeclared identifier: 'maException'
    ReadTimeout := 0;
    UserMode := [];
    Connect();
    Join(IrcChan);
  end;
  ReadLn;

end.
```

I've tried so far everything i could think of, but, although the app is connected successfully, it won't return any raw message... What am i missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TdIRC` uses an internal worker thread to receive data. The `OnRaw` event is triggered when that thread is parsing data. The thread uses `TThread.Synchronize()` to do that parsing.  Since your main thread does not have an active VCL message loop, you can pump the `Synchronize()` queue manually.  After you connect, call the `CheckSynchronize()` function from the `Classes` unit in a loop while you are connected to IRC, eg:

```
begin 
  ...
  Connect; 
  try
    Join(IrcChan); 
    do
      CheckSynchronize;
      Sleep(10);
    until SomeCondition;
  finally
    Disconnect;
  end;
  ...  
end.
```

For good measure, you can assign a handler to the `WakeMainThread` event in the `Classes` unit to help control when `CheckSynchronize()` should be called, so the main thread can go to sleep while the IRC connection is idle, eg:

```
program Project1;     

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}     

uses     
  SysUtils,     
  Classes,     
  Math,     
  IdBaseComponent,     
  IdComponent,     
  IdTCPConnection,     
  IdTCPClient,     
  IdIRC;     

type     
  TEvents = class     
  private
    FSyncEvent: TEvent;
  public     
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Raw(Sender: TObject; AUser: TIdIRCUser; ACommand, AContent: String; var Suppress: Boolean);     
    procedure Wake(Sender: TObject);
    procedure CheckSync;
  end;     

function Log(s: string): string;      
begin      
  result := FormatDateTime('[hh:nn:ss] ', Time) + s;      
end;      

constructor TEvents.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  FSyncEvent := TEvent.Create(nil, False, False, '');
end;

destructor TEvents.Destroy;
begin
  FSyncEvent.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TEvents.Raw(Sender: TObject; AUser: TIdIRCUser; ACommand, AContent: String; var Suppress: Boolean);      
begin      
  Log(AUser.Nick+' '+ACommand+' '+AContent);      
end;      

procedure TEvents.Wake(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FSyncEvent.SetEvent;
end;

procedure TEvents.CheckSync;
begin
  FSyncEvent.WaitFor(Infinite);
  CheckSynchronize;
end;

const     
  IrcServ = 'gr.irc.gr';     
  IrcPort = 6667;     
  IrcChan = '#lalala';     

var      
  Irc: TidIRC;      
  Event: TEvents;      
  uName, rName: string;      

begin
  Event := TEvents.Create;       
  try
    WakeMainThread := Event.Wake;
    Irc := TIdIRC.Create(nil);       
    try
      Irc.OnRaw := Event.Raw;       
      Randomize;       
      Write('Nickname: ');       
      ReadLn(uName);       
      rName := 'IDM' + IntToStr(RandomRange(1000, 9999)) + uName;       
      with Irc do begin       
        AltNick := 'IDM' + IntToStr(RandomRange(1000, 9999)) + uName;
        Nick := rName;       
        Username := rName;       
        RealName := 'I.D.M.';       
        Host := IrcHost;       
        Port := IrcPort;       
        //MaxLineAction := maException;  <-- [ERROR] Undeclared identifier: 'maException'       
        ReadTimeout := 0;       
        UserMode := [];       
        Connect;       
        try
          Join(IrcChan);       
          do
            Event.CheckSync;
          until SomeCondition;
        finally
          Disconnect;
        end;
      end;       
    finally
      Irc.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Event.Free;
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Remy. Would it be possible for your to explain with some code how to "pump the message queue"? The only thread i found in idirc.pas is `TIdIrcReadThread`. I tried to catch it with a custom thread in project but no luck.

Comment: Does a console app actually have an Application that has a ProcessMessages() method?

Comment: @rudy It does if the project uses Forms.pas. That's monstrous overkill though. Just use while GetMessage(...) do begin TranslateMessage(...); DispatchMessage(...); end; to pump the queue.

Comment: @David: Overkill indeed. It would never occur to me to use Forms in a console app.

Comment: Actually, now that I think of it, there is a simpler solution. In D7, `TThread.Synchronize()` puts sync requests into an in-memory queue which can be pumped manually using the `CheckSynchronize()` function in the Classes unit, without involving any message loop at all. I have updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @Remy awesome! I had no idea about `SyncObjs`. Thanks for your effort and your time!!