# Errors in source for connect IRC in Delphi

Tags: delphi

hi was reading the response of a well explained in this forum post and I wanted to put the code into practice but the problem is that the code gives me many errors that occur do not 
understand why, I'm using delphi xe2 and the code is as follows:

Post : [Delphi 7: Handling events in console application (TidIRC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364434/delphi-7-handling-events-in-console-application-tidirc)

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  Classes,
  Math,
  IdBaseComponent,
  IdComponent,
  IdTCPConnection,
  IdTCPClient,
  IdIRC;

type
  TEvents = class
  private
    FSyncEvent: TEvent;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Raw(Sender: TObject; AUser: TIdIRCUser; ACommand, AContent: String; var Suppress: Boolean);
    procedure Wake(Sender: TObject);
    procedure CheckSync;
  end;

function Log(s: string): string;
begin
  result := FormatDateTime('[hh:nn:ss] ', Time) + s;
end;

constructor TEvents.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  FSyncEvent := TEvent.Create(nil, False, False, '');
end;

destructor TEvents.Destroy;
begin
  FSyncEvent.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TEvents.Raw(Sender: TObject; AUser: TIdIRCUser; ACommand, AContent: String; var Suppress: Boolean);
begin
  Log(AUser.Nick+' '+ACommand+' '+AContent);
end;

procedure TEvents.Wake(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FSyncEvent.SetEvent;
end;

procedure TEvents.CheckSync;
begin
  FSyncEvent.WaitFor(Infinite);
  CheckSynchronize;
end;

const
  IrcServ = 'gr.irc.gr';
  IrcPort = 6667;
  IrcChan = '#lalala';

var
  Irc: TidIRC;
  Event: TEvents;
  uName, rName: string;

begin
  Event := TEvents.Create;
  try
    WakeMainThread := Event.Wake;
    Irc := TIdIRC.Create(nil);
    try
      Irc.OnRaw := Event.Raw;
      Randomize;
      Write('Nickname: ');
      ReadLn(uName);
      rName := 'IDM' + IntToStr(RandomRange(1000, 9999)) + uName;
      with Irc do begin
        AltNick := 'IDM' + IntToStr(RandomRange(1000, 9999)) + uName;
        Nick := rName;
        Username := rName;
        RealName := 'I.D.M.';
        Host := IrcHost;
        Port := IrcPort;
        //MaxLineAction := maException;  <-- [ERROR] Undeclared identifier: 'maException'
        ReadTimeout := 0;
        UserMode := [];
        Connect;
        try
          Join(IrcChan);
          do
            Event.CheckSync;
          until SomeCondition;
        finally
          Disconnect;
        end;
      end;
    finally
      Irc.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Event.Free;
  end;
end.
```

And I returned as a thousand errors

```
[DCC Error] irc.dpr(18): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'TEvent'
[DCC Error] irc.dpr(22): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'TIdIRCUser'
[DCC Error] irc.dpr(35): E2066 Missing operator or semicolon
[DCC Error] irc.dpr(35): E2034 Too many actual parameters
[DCC Error] irc.dpr(35): E2034 Too many actual parameters
[DCC Error] irc.dpr(40): E2066 Missing operator or semicolon
[DCC Error] irc.dpr(44): E2005 'TIdIRCUser' is not a type identifier
[DCC Error] irc.dpr(46): E2029 ')' expected but identifier 'Nick' found
[DCC Error] irc.dpr(46): E2029 'END' expected but ')' found
[DCC Error] irc.dpr(51): E2066 Missing operator or semicolon
[DCC Error] irc.dpr(56): E2066 Missing operator or semicolon
[DCC Error] irc.dpr(76): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TIdContext' and 'TObject'
[DCC Error] irc.dpr(82): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'AltNick'
[DCC Error] irc.dpr(83): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'Nick'
[DCC Error] irc.dpr(86): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'IrcHost'
[DCC Error] irc.dpr(94): E2029 Statement expected but 'DO' found
[DCC Error] irc.dpr(96): E2125 EXCEPT or FINALLY expected
[DCC Error] irc.dpr(100): E2125 EXCEPT or FINALLY expected
[DCC Error] irc.dpr(104): E2029 'END' expected but 'FINALLY' found
[DCC Error] irc.dpr(106): E2029 '.' expected but ';' found
```

could someone explain why I do not recognize any variable ?

Answer (score 4):

The code you showed was written for an old version of Delphi and an old version of Indy.  An updated version of the code would look more like this instead:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  Classes,
  Math,
  SycObjs,
  IdGlobal,
  IdBaseComponent,
  IdComponent,
  IdTCPConnection,
  IdTCPClient,
  IdIOHandler,
  IdIRC;

type
  TEvents = class
  private
    FSyncEvent: TEvent;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Raw(ASender: TIdContext; AIn: Boolean; const AMessage: String);
    procedure Wake(Sender: TObject);
    procedure CheckSync;
  end;

function Log(s: string): string;
begin
  Result := FormatDateTime('[hh:nn:ss] ', Time) + s;
end;

constructor TEvents.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  FSyncEvent := TEvent.Create(nil, False, False, '');
end;

destructor TEvents.Destroy;
begin
  FSyncEvent.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TEvents.Raw(ASender: TIdContext; AIn: Boolean; const AMessage: String);
begin
  Log(iif(AIn, 'Send', 'Recv')  + ': ' + AMessage);
end;

procedure TEvents.Wake(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FSyncEvent.SetEvent;
end;

procedure TEvents.CheckSync;
begin
  FSyncEvent.WaitFor(Infinite);
  CheckSynchronize;
end;

const
  IrcServ = 'gr.irc.gr';
  IrcPort = 6667;
  IrcChan = '#lalala';

var
  Irc: TidIRC;
  Event: TEvents;
  uName, rName: string;
begin
  Event := TEvents.Create;
  try
    WakeMainThread := Event.Wake;
    Irc := TIdIRC.Create(nil);
    try
      Irc.OnRaw := Event.Raw;
      Randomize;
      Write('Nickname: ');
      ReadLn(uName);
      rName := 'IDM' + IntToStr(RandomRange(1000, 9999)) + uName;
      with Irc do
      begin
        AltNickname := 'IDM' + IntToStr(RandomRange(1000, 9999)) + uName;
        Nickname := rName;
        Username := rName;
        RealName := 'I.D.M.';
        Host := IrcHost;
        Port := IrcPort;
        ReadTimeout := 0;
        UserMode := [];
        Connect;
        try
          IOHandler.MaxLineAction := maException;
          Join(IrcChan);
          do
            Event.CheckSync;
          until SomeCondition;
        finally
          Disconnect;
        end;
      end;
    finally
      Irc.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Event.Free;
  end;
end.
```